# Is "There + 'intransitive verb' ..." okay?

Tags: verbs

Since "there exists a dog with black fur" is okay, is it generally true that "there + 'intransitive verb' ..." also okay?

For example, can I say "There thrive trees in the park" to mean "Trees in the park thrive"?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this has much to do with intransitive or transitive verbs.

*There is a tree in the park* is a fine sentence. If you look at the [ODO](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/there_1) entry for *there*, you see it gets combined with *be* in virtually all cases.

In sentences with verbs that do *not* denote "existence", *there*  seems unnatural. Your first example, *there exists*, is virtually synonymous with *there is*.

This even goes for a sentence like:

> There are trees thriving in the park.

*Thriving* is attributive to *trees*, and the main idea of the sentence is still *there **exist** trees* (and they are in the park, and they are thriving).

Comment: How about, *at the end of the platform there appeared three enemy agents carrying rifles*?

Comment: @Araucaria If you read _appeared_ as a form of _coming into existence_, there's nothing wrong with it :) You could _not_ get away with _there carried three agents rifles_, but you _could_ say (changing the meaning of _there_!): _there, three agents appeared, carrying rifles_ or _there, agents carried rifles_. Not that _at the end of the platform_ is just a ruse, it doesn't affect the meaning or use of _there_, unless you move _there_ to the beginning of the sentence (and add some comma's).

Comment: That's not quite on the button. Presentational *there* as it is sometimes called, is perfectly licit. It usually happens when the NP is discourse new and very long ... That sentence I gave there is perfectly fine!

Comment: @Araucaria: I never said it was wrong :) _appeared_ works. Are you saying that _there carried three men rifles_ is also correct?

Comment: No, that one's definitely wonky! :)